# Encoding DOCX to be Sent via email

Tags: perl, attachment, mime, docx

I am writing a little Perl app to send emails internally where I work, but I am having troubles with attachments.  Now, I can hear all of you screaming "use MIME::Lite", but it aint that easy - management rules tell me I am unable to use anything from the cpan...

Anyhow, I am using MIME::Base64 to encode any attachements I am sending.  I am using Net::SMTP for the email side of things.

encoding is done as such (straight out of the Perldoc page):

```
my $encoded = "";
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);
open (FILE, "7857084216_9816ae9bec_b.jpg") or die "$!\n";
while (read(FILE, $buf, 60*57)) {
$encoded .= encode_base64($buf);
}
```

The relevant Net::SMTP code is as follows:

```
use Net::SMTP;
$smtp = Net::SMTP->new("mailserver",
                Hello => 'somedomain.com.au',
                Timeout => 60,
                Debug => 0,
                );
$smtp->mail(<services\@somedomain.com.au>);
$smtp->to(<me\@somedomain.com.au>);
$smtp->cc(<another\@somedomain.com.au>);
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("Subject: testing 123\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: me\@somedomain.com.au\n");
$smtp->datasend("CC: another\@somedomain.com.au\n");
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: multipart/mixed;\n\tboundary=\"$boundary\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("<p> Test Email!</p>\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-type: image/jpeg; name=\"7857084216_9816ae9bec_b.jpg\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-ID: \n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"7857084216_9816ae9bec_b.jpg\"\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-transfer-encoding: base64\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("$encoded");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("--$boundary--\n");
$smtp->dataend;
$smtp->quit;
```

At this moment, I am directing these emails through to myself and reading them using Outlook 2010
When sending images (such as jpegs), I am not having any issues at all - everything seems to decode OK byte for byte as far as I can see.
When I am sending docx type files with just plain text, everything seems fine.
But, when I am sending docx files with images inserted, the files are corrupting.

Not being an expert in mail sending and attaching, I am at a bit of a loss.  How should I be encoding docx files for attaching to emails?  Any help would be appreciated!

Also forgot to mention, I have attempted to set the content-type accordingly: Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: How exactly are files corrupted? They are not openinig at all, or something is missing?

Comment: You can edit your question (edit link is below the tags). You didn't answered my comment however.

Comment: Petr, It depends - Generally when opening them in Word, I get an error message telling me "The File is Corrupt and cannot be opened".  After that message, I am getting "Word found unreadable content in "file.docx".  Do you want to recover....".  Sometimes when I attempt a recovery, it works OK, other times, it fails.

Comment: Have you verified that file is encoded with `base64` correctly? Try do decode is right after encoding. File type should be totally indifferent to the result, AFAIK.

Comment: I'm guessing the file type is a red herring, and you are bumping up against some size limitation when files get too large. If your base64 data is all on one horrible line, wrap it with newlines. (Your encoding loop could use an overhaul anyway; it looks rather inefficient.)

Comment: OK, I have tried to encode/decode and have found something - it appears that I have to set the file handles to binmode for it to work. Once these are set, picture and files encode/decode fine.....I have applied it to the code above (obviously, only on the read) and no joy yet.

Comment: I think I have found the issue:

    Content-type: application/octet-stream;

This seemed to have sent it straight through, no issues with either Outlook 2010 and 2003

Thanks for the comments and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and it does appear that the 'content-type' does seem to make a difference.  According to what I found, I replaced all the Content-type calls, that include Base64 encoded data with the following:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream;
```

This seemed to have sent it straight through, no issues with either Outlook 2010 and 2003.  I have tested it against binary files, plain text, ect and all seems to work OK in my current environment.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen before and usually comes down to just the incorrect mime type or mime structure.  You mention you tried adding the mime type, so that might indicate that the mime structure might be a little off.  I've seen this with xslx and csv files.  CSV would come in find since the decoder assumes text, but if you don't have the right Mime for binary data it will always attempt to convert to ascii.  I realize this around an xslx vs docx, but I think the same principles apply.

Here is a snip of an sample email I'm generating (Using Mime:Lite), but might help.

```
    From: me@example.com
To: example@example.com
Subject: Example
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_----------=_13433203262384120"


--_----------=_13433203262384120
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

<body>Hello,<br>
<p>EMAIL BODY</p>
<p>Thanks,<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Blah</body>

--_----------=_13433203262384120
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; name="sample.xlsx"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.xlsx"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBBQAAAAIAAFk+kDm/EEvVgEAACQFAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbMVUS28CIRC+
N+l/IFybXdRD0zSuHvo4tia1P4DC6BJZIAxa/fed3a32EesjmvQCgfleQ8j0h8vKsgVENN4VvJt3
OAOnvDZuWvDX8WN2wxkm6bS03kHBV4B8OLi86I9XAZAR22HBy5TCrRCoSqgk5j6Ao8rEx0omOsap
CFLN5BREr9O5Fsq7BC5lqdbgg/49TOTcJvawpOs2SQSLnN21wNqr4DIEa5RMVBcLp3+5ZJ8OOTEb
DJYm4BUBOBNbLZrSnw5r4jM9TjQa2EjG9CQrggnt1Sj6gIII+W6ZLUH9ZGIUkMa8IkoOdSINOgsk
CTEZ+Eq901z5CMe7r5+pZh9qubQC08oCntwshghSYwmQKpu3ovusE30qaNfuyQEamX2O7z7O3ryf
....  <Snipped>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--_----------=_13433203262384120--
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would have thought that using the correct Content Types should make a difference, but from my experience today/yesterday, unless I specified it as application/octet-stream (as per my answer above).  Cheers